# Chrome not always applying perspective during css3 animation

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have what appears to be a random bug in Chrome where the perspective of CSS3 3D Transform is ignored until the last frame of the animation. It doesn't happen each time, and there doesn't appear to be a pattern.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6gCBx/15/

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">click me</div>
```

css

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #444444;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
}

#holder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.tilt{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(40deg);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#holder').click(function(){
    $('#holder').toggleClass('tilt');
});
```

Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this as well.  I'm guessing it's a bug, but you can avoid it by adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to your `html, body` CSS rule.

Comment: I did try backface-visibility hidden a while back but perhaps I put it in the wrong place, or its been fixed since. Either way it works now! Thanks.